# Generate Simple Mad Lib

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, var

I am trying to create a very simple mad lib using Javascript. I am mostly finished however my code will not run. Is there something I am forgetting to add or have added improperly?

HTML:

```
   <body>
  <h1>Mad Libs</h1>

<div id="story">
  <p>A thing:</p>
    <input type="text" id="thing">
  <p>A name:</p>
    <input type="text" id="title">
  <p>An adjective ending in "ily":</p>
    <input type="text" id="adjective">
  <p>A name:</p>
    <input type="text" id="noun">
</div>

<br/>

  <button id="libbutton" onclick="madLibs()">Create lib</button>
  <div id="mystory"></div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function madLibs() {

  var mystory = document.getElementById("mystory");
  var thing = document.getElementById("thing").value;
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
  var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;

  mystory.innerHTML = "Space: the final " + thing + ". " "These are the voyages of the starship " + title + ". Its five-year mission: to explore " + adjective + " new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldy go where no " + noun + " has gone before.";
}
```

Comment: Open up your console - do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string". Am I missing something?

Comment: What line is that being thrown on? (Should say a line number / click it to head to the source)

Comment: Ah found it! It was as simple as an extra " symbol. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: No problem :D - always have that console open when working!

Answer (score 0):

You've just got some quotes messed up in the mystory.innerHTML portion.

```
function madLibs() {

  var mystory = document.getElementById("mystory");
  var thing = document.getElementById("thing").value;
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
  var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;

  mystory.innerHTML = "Space: the final " + thing + ". These are the voyages of the starship " + title + ". Its five-year mission: to explore " + adjective + " new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldy go where no " + noun + " has gone before.";
}
```

[Working codepen here.](http://codepen.io/twwoodward/pen/WoyrxM)

Answer (score 0):

There was a double quote(") near thing:

```
function madLibs() {

var story = document.getElementById('story').getElementsByTagName('input');
var myobj = {};
for(var i=0; i<story.length; i++){
    myobj[story[i].id] = story[i].value;
}
// add innerHTML
document.getElementById('mystory').innerHTML = "Space: the final " + myobj.thing + ". These are the voyages of the starship " + myobj.title + ". Its five-year mission: to explore " + myobj.adjective + " new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldy go where no " + myobj.noun + " has gone before.";
```

}